# Issue with DateTimeParseException when using STRICT resolver style

Tags: java-8, java-time

I am trying to parse a date string using the following pattern: `yyMMdd` and the `STRICT` resolver as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDate.parse(expiryDate, formatter);
```

I get the following `DateTimeParseException`:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '160501' could not be
>   parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor:
>   {YearOfEra=2016, MonthOfYear=5, DayOfMonth=1},ISO of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

When I swith to the default resolve style, i.e. `ResolverStyle.SMART` it allows such dates as 30th of February.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I regret that the `java.time`-design is not clever enough to recognize that - in absence of era field - the year-of-era (symbol y) should be handled like proleptic gregorian year (symbol u). In addition, the original ISO-8601-paper does not say anything about eras. Therefore a plain year-month-day-combination should really be handled like what ISO says, ignoring the era and using the proleptic gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The strict resolver requires an era to go with YearOfEra. Change your pattern to use "u" instead of "y" and it will work, ie. "uuMMdd".

Comment: Hi i used `uuuu` in place of `yyyy` but still it allow `02-31-2019`. code:

`    @FutureOrPresent
    @DateTimeFormat( iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE )
    @JsonFormat( pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu" )
    private LocalDate start;`

Comment: also used `@DateTimeFormat( iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE, pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu" )` but effect.

Answer (score 4):

While JodaStephen has nicely explained the reason for the exception and given one good solution (use `uu` rather than `yy`), I am offering a couple of other possible solutions:

1. The obvious one that you probably don’t want: leave the resolver style at `SMART` (the default). In other words either leave out `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` completely or change it to `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART)`.
2. Provide a default era.

For the second option here is a code example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyMMdd")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, 1)
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    String expiryDate = "160501";
    LocalDate result = LocalDate.parse(expiryDate, formatter);
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is:

> 2016-05-01

Where the last solution may make a difference compared to using `uu` in the format pattern:

1. It allows us to use a format pattern that is given to us where we cannot control whether pattern letter `u` or `y` is used.
2. With pattern letter `y` it will fail with an exception if the string contains a negative year. Depending on your situation and requirements this may be desirable or unacceptable.

Edit: The second argument to `parseDefaulting()` may also be written `IsoEra.CE.getValue()` rather than just `1` to make it clear that we are specifying the *current era* (CE; also often called *Anno Domini* or *AD*).