# LocalDate DateTimeFormatter problems

Tags: java, localdate

I have read the manuals and I'm completely at a loss as to why this code does not work.

```
    // Date Entered must be valid
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    try {
        String dateEntered = lossDateMonth + "/" + lossDateDay + "/" + lossDateYear; // Slash to match UI

        System.out.println(dateEntered);
        LocalDate dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(dateEntered, dateTimeFormatter);
```

The println statement prints:  07/29/2015

The last line throws an exception:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '07/29/2015' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2015, DayOfMonth=29, MonthOfYear=7},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

I read the manual on this and it says this sort of thing happens if you try to resolve a date that does not exist, for example September 31st.  Even in the error, the parser seems to understand that I am asking about July 29, 2015, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the pattern `"MM/dd/yyyy"` by `"MM/dd/uuuu"`. Have a look in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [IsoChronology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html). The problem is that when using `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` the formatter expects an unique identifier to the year which is provided by `uuuu` where `yyyy` is the *year of era*. This is to *strictly* validate the values. The uniqueness is given by the fact that `uuuu` can be negative.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103603/issue-with-datetimeparseexception-when-using-strict-resolver-style), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era) for related posts.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!  I also edited to remove code that's irrelevant to the problem.