# Java DateTimeFormatter is not parsing as expected

Tags: java

I tried DateTimeFormatter to parse input date to `dd/MM/yyyy`. I have used below code

`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` is failing to parse the date

```
  DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    
       
            try {
                LocalDate.parse(dateField, dateFormatter);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Input: `30/04/2018`

```
Error:Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=4, YearOfEra=2018, DayOfMonth=30},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

It is also failing for leap years.

Comment: Make the pattern `"dd/MM/uuuu"`... Or leave the `ResolverStyle`, but if you want a `ResolverStyle.STRICT` you will have to use year (`u`) instead of year-of-era (`y`).

Comment: @deHaar — or provide a default era using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseDefaulting()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. that should be added as another answer... Or added to one of the existing ones, but I don't have time left.

Comment: @deHaar I think I found a better fit for an original question. I have added it and written [a new answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708336/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options (here, where one is using the `ResolverStyle` you are showing in your code example):

- use a `ResolverStyle.STRICT` explicitly ⇒ parses *year* `u` only
- use a default `ResolverStyle` ⇒ *year-of-era* `y` or *year* `u` will be parsed

The following example shows the differences in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "30/04/2018";
    // first formatter with year-of-era but no resolver style
    DateTimeFormatter dtfY = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    // second one with year and a strict resolver style
    DateTimeFormatter dtfU = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
                                                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    // parse
    LocalDate localDateU = LocalDate.parse(date, dtfU);
    LocalDate localDateY = LocalDate.parse(date, dtfY);
    // print results
    System.out.println(localDateU);
    System.out.println(localDateY);
}
```

The output is

```
2018-04-30
2018-04-30
```

so both `DateTimeFormatter`s parse the very same `String`, but the one without a `ResolverStyle` explicitly attached will use `ResolverStyle.SMART` by default according to the [JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle(java.time.format.ResolverStyle)).

Of course, a pattern with *year* (`u`) will be parsed by `ResolverStyle.SMART`, too, so

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
```

would be an option as well.

A good explanation of the difference between *year-of-era* and *year* can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is using `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` requires to use year pattern **uuuu** instead of **yyyy** (i.e. "year" instead of "year-of-era")